# How to give access to service methods to different clients

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I am new to asp.net web services. I am creating a sample web service(.ASMX) with ten methods and one interface. I have two clients A and B, I want to expose the first four methods to client A and next 6 methods to client B.

Please tell me how to give permission for those methods to corresponding clients.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you begin with this article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc948343.aspx

In this you can find "Authorization within WCF services".

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/86851/how-to-give-access-to-service-methods-to-different-clien.aspx

Comment: Is this what solved your problem? Did you switch to WCF?

Answer (score -1):

Simple.

Provide different Authentication key(alphanumeric) to client A and Client B.

Methods will be decorated with required Authentication key i.e. Match with simple If.

And good to go.

this is simple approach, you can always go with complex one and also you can try WCF.